# How to get a static resource URL to work in a Community without a gack?

Tags: community, lightning-community, static-resources, gack

I have a static resource that opens fine using this URL from the normal Salesforce desktop where the domain is https://flow-flow-3628-dev-ed.lightning.force.com):

- /resource/1594633705000/myns_mystaticresource

But when trying to do the same in a community I get a **gack** (internal Salesforce error) for all these URLs (where I believe the first one is the documented one to use). The domain in this case is https://flow-flow-3628-dev-ed.preview.salesforce-communities.com:

- /portal/resource/1594633705000/myns_mystaticresource
- /portal/resource/myns_mystaticresource
- /resource/1594633705000/myns_mystaticresource
- /resource/myns_mystaticresource

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to only be a problem in the community preview view. When using the normal URL of https://sandbox-flow-flow-3628-dev-ed-1734756c3da.cs97.force.com/ the expected url works:

- /portal/resource/1594633705000/myns_mystaticresource